# bootstrap3-wysiwyg - remove outdent and indent buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I remove outdent and indent buttons form the toolbar. I found the option to remove the list where are the buttons stored, but not the buttons. Is it possible. I tried this, but this doesn't work:

```
    $('.editor').wysihtml5({
        toolbar: {
          "font-styles": true, //Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc. Default true
          "emphasis": true, //Italics, bold, etc. Default true
          "lists": true, //(Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers. Default true
          "html": false, //Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML. Default false
          "link": true, //Button to insert a link. Default true
          "image": true, //Button to insert an image. Default true,
          "color": false, //Button to change color of font
          "blockquote": true, //Blockquote
        },
        lists: {
          unordered: 'Unordered list',
          ordered: 'Ordered list',
        },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late with this answer, but in case this helps anyone.

The quick (dirty) way - hide the buttons using CSS:

```
a[data-wysihtml5-command="Outdent"],
a[data-wysihtml5-command="Indent"] {
    display:none !important;
}
```

The better solution is to use custom templates:

```
var myCustomTemplates = {
    emphasis : function(locale) {
        return "<li>" +
            "<div class='btn-group'>" +
            "<a data-wysihtml5-command='bold' title='Bold' class='btn btn-none btn-default' ><span style='font-weight:700'>B</span></a>" +
            "<a data-wysihtml5-command='italic' title='Italics' class='btn btn-none btn-default' ><span style='font-style:italic'>I</span></a>" +
            "<a data-wysihtml5-command='underline' title='Underline' class='btn btn-none btn-default' ><span style='text-decoration:underline'>U</span></a>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</li>";
    },
    lists : function(locale) {
        return "<li>" +
            "<div class='btn-group'>" +
            "<a data-wysihtml5-command='insertUnorderedList' title='Unordered list' class='btn btn-none btn-default' ><span class='fa fa-list-ul'></span></a>" +
            "<a data-wysihtml5-command='insertOrderedList' title='Ordered list' class='btn btn-none btn-default' ><span class='fa fa-list-ol'></span></a>" +
            //"<a data-wysihtml5-command='Outdent' title='Outdent' class='btn btn-none btn-default' ><span class='fa fa-outdent'></span></a>" +
            //"<a data-wysihtml5-command='Indent' title='Indent' class='btn btn-none btn-default'><span class='fa fa-indent'></span></a>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</li>";
    }
}

$('.texteditor').wysihtml5({
    toolbar: {
        "font-styles": false, //Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc. Default true
        "emphasis": true, //Italics, bold, etc. Default true
        "lists": true, //(Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers. Default true
        "html": true, //Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML. Default false
        "link": true, //Button to insert a link. Default true
        "image": false, //Button to insert an image. Default true,
        "color": false, //Button to change color of font
        "blockquote": false, //Blockquote
    },
    customTemplates: myCustomTemplates
});
```

Hence the custom template above returns only the first 2 lists template buttons

(since the last 2 are commented out in the template),

plus it also adjusts the styling buttons in the emphasis template 
to B I U